# Flutter here map android emulator map display problem?

Tags: flutter, here-api, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

What is the cause of this situation, I wrote to the hereMap support team, but no one responded.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwV7R.jpg

EDİT: The latest version(4.12.7.0) of Heremap fixed this problem. please update SDK to latest version.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this issue as well.
As of the moment of writing this answer, the HERE SDK =< v3.12.3 is not compatible yet with Flutter 3.x due to [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/103630) with platform views, as described in their release log [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.12.3.0/release_notes/).
Solution is to use FVM and run the app using Flutter version 2.10.5.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `HereMap` in your `Stack` with an image. Then you will see that this is not related to your emulator nor the map. From the screenshot it looks like a problem with your visual tree.

Comment: ios emulator works fine here I don't use stack widget for maps map area the problem is like canvas error